# git rebase from a url/path

Tags: git

Why can I not `rebase` from the same location that I can `pull`?  For example, if I am in a pository I can pull from another repository:

```
git pull /path/to/other
```

But I cannot rebase from that other repository; the following fails:

```
git rebase /path/to/other
```

The help for `rebase` doesn't mention any refspec's, so I don't know how, or even if, I can/should specify them.

How can I `rebase` from a different location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because `git pull` and `git rebase` do completely different things.

What `git pull` does:

1. Retrieve commits from some *remote repository* and place them into remote-tracking branches.
2. Merge the remote-tracking branch corresponding with the current branch into the current branch.

What `git rebase` does:

1. Move commits from the current branch on top of another *branch*.

(In both cases, those are just the defaults.)

The main difference is that `git pull` operates on *remote repositories*, while `git rebase` operates on *branches*. That's why `git rebase /path/to/other` doesn't work, `/path/to/other` is not a branch.

But if you want to do what `git pull` does, except you want to do `rebase` instead of `merge`, you can do that: use `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: So `git pull` is really just a convenience wrapper around a combination of `fetch+merge` or `fetch+rebase`, can I say that?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, yeah, exactly. It even says that in the documentation: “In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.”

Answer (score 3):

```
git pull --rebase /path/to/other
```